# The purpose of creating anonymous types in AutoFixture for class under tests?

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, autofixture

I recently started using AutoFixture library (http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) for Unit Testing and I quite like it.

I got this code sample from the AutoFixture CodePlex website. My question is in regards to line number 8.

```
1.   [TestMethod]
2.   public void IntroductoryTest()
3.   {
4.        // Fixture setup
5.        Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
6.
7.        int expectedNumber = fixture.CreateAnonymous<int>();
8.        MyClass sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyClass>();
9.        
10.        // Exercise system
11.        int result = sut.Echo(expectedNumber);
12.        
13.        // Verify outcome
14.        Assert.AreEqual<int>(expectedNumber, result, "Echo");
15.        // Teardown
16.    }
```

I can't understand, why we need to create an anonymous object of the class under test.

```
        MyClass sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyClass>();
```

The class should be the real object IMO. For an example..

```
        var sut = new MyClass();
```

My question is, what is the real benefit of creating an anonymous object to test against?

Comment: Autofixture is now at: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the trivial case you are correct - there is no material difference.

However, [SUT API Encapsulation](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Utility%20Method.html#SUT%20API%20Encapsulation) has its uses -- as your System Under Test and its [Fixture Object](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/03/16/FixtureObject.aspx)s get more interesting than something with a default ctor (does it really have *no* dependencies?), e.g.:

- `MyClass` requires stuff to be fed into it's constructors
- `MyClass has read/write properties that you don't want default values to apply to (programming by coincidence)
- the bulding of `MyClass` has anything else you want to [apply a policy to](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/discussions/231340)

Then the power of having a [Sut Factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/02/13/SUTFactory.aspx) involved starts coming into play, letting extraneous code fall away and allowing you to apply cross-cutting concerns to the process.

EDIT: For some reason [@Brad Wilson saw fit to repost this article](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/BradWilson/~3/MfrMrNJwdTk/the-testable-object-pattern.html) which is kinda salient

Comment: +1 Basically, it decouples the unit test from the constructor signature of the SUT, thus making the tests more robust when facing refactorings.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you Ruben and Mark.